# UITableView - Deleting rows with animation

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to delete row from tableview using animation however in most cases it gets stuck. 1 in 15 tries will result in this animation being played. This is what my delete action looks like:

```
func contextualDeleteAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                                    title: "Delete") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in

                                            Model().context.delete(notesArray[indexPath.row])
                                            notesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom)
                                            Model().saveItems()                             

    }
    action.title = "Delete"

    return action
}
```

This is what it looks like when it gets stucked when swiping.
[image: Stucked when swiping]

When pressing delete button instead.

[image]

I've also tried to use tableView.beginUpdate() and tableView.endUpdate() but didn't get different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have forgotten your primary duty in this method: you must call the completion handler!

```
    Model().context.delete(notesArray[indexPath.row])
    notesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom)
    Model().saveItems()
    completionHandler(true) // <-- look!
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift 4`, you can perform a delete animation just like the iPhone Messages animation.

Use this:

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

Comment: tried to use that as well same thing happens, it's just different syntax

Comment: @MartinDichtler. You question isn’t clear enough, may I ask where you perform your animation?

Comment: trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt, the function above is called in to configure the action

Comment: Yes i'm aware, @matt was able to answer it i didn't fulfil completion handler which was causing this to not animate.

Comment: I love every answer @matt gives. An inspirational guy. Good luck with your code